# R floors a value by default. Why not ceiling() or round()?

Tags: r

Consider the following silly example:

```
x <- 50.8 # number of rows
y <- 100 # number of columns

res <- array(dim = c(x, y, 1))
dim(res) # dimensions of res = 50 100 1
```

Clearly x must be a whole number.

In this case (and all cases), R rounds down by taking floor(x).

Is there any specific reason as to why R uses floor() instead of ceiling() or round()?

It seems to me that there is noting special about floor().

Comment: The reason is that `dim` coerces numbers to `integer`s. Compare with `as.integer(x)`. So this has nothing to do with `floor` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** The `dim` argument of `array` coerces numbers to integers.

---

From `?array` (bold face mine)

> dim: the dim attribute for the array to be created, that is an **integer vector** of length one or more giving the maximal indices in each dimension.

So `c(x, y, 1)` will be coerced to an `integer` vector. If we dig a little deeper, we find that this happens in the C code implementation of `array` using the C helper function `asInteger` (see [lines 101 and 109 of the source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/77ce5ba9d509a160e89658c8b3639f400969fc24/src/main/array.c)).